# How can I see the size of the Squid cache?

Tags: server, squid

Anyone know how to see the space on squid? I mean the cache space on the squid that is being used, like the available space and used space of the cache itself, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check squid cache configuration file for the size of squid cache.

Goto Terminal and type the following,

```
grep ^cache_dir /etc/squid/squid.conf
```

> cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 15000 16 256

Here **15000** is your squid cache directory size.

**NOTE:** Please note that the squid configuration file is squid.conf

If you want to know how much data is currently cached,then type the following in terminal

```
sudo du -sh /var/spool/squid
```

> 18M    /var/spool/squid

So **18MB** data is currently cached here.